# Find older records in a group in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm trying to find older records within a group of a SQL table, so that I can delete them. But I'm having trouble even selecting them.

Table looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is keep only the top 3 newest changes on each issue, and I want to delete the older records.

What is the SQL required to find the ones not in the top 3 most recent for each issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the SQL required to find the ones not in the top 3 most recent for each issue?

If you are running MySQL 8.0, use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by issue_id order by change_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn > 3
```

In ealier versions, you can emulate this with a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
where (
    select count(*) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.issue_id = t.issue_id and t1.change_date > t.change_date
) >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB! I think I have it working. Question.. wouldn't the last part be > 3 (not >= 3) if I want to preserve the first 3?

Comment: @ArcticCoder: no that's `>= 3` indeed. The subquery counts the records that have a greater `change_date`. If there are 3 records with a greater date, then it means the current record is ranked 4th.

Comment: Ah, I get it -- very slick! This saved me a couple hours. Thanks again.